# Can't use delete endpoint from API using DIO and provider

Tags: flutter, provider, dio

I need help with accessing delete endpoint from API. I have provided all the requirements needed for the API to remove the article from the reading list but got an error message that is `page not found`. Here is my endpoint:

```
https://13.210.163.192:8080/users/reading-lists/save/:id
```

This is my service:

```
Future<String> deleteArticleFromReadingList(
      {required String token, required String id}) async {
    try {
      String url = 'https://13.210.163.192:8080/users/reading-lists/save/$id';

      final Response response = await dio.delete(
        url,
        options: Options(
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
          },
        ),
      );
      final String message = response.data['meta']['message'].toString();
      return message;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

My provider:

```
class ArticleListPostProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  MyState myState = MyState.initial;
  List<ReadingListModel> readingList = [];
  int checkedIndex = -1;
  final ArticleService _articleService = ArticleService();
  final ReadingListService _readingListService = ReadingListService();
  late SharedPreferences _loginData;
  String _message = '';
  List<String> savedArticleIds = [];

  ArticleListPostProvider() {
    initializeSharedPreferences();
  }

  void initializeSharedPreferences() async {
    changeState(MyState.loading);
    _loginData = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    changeState(MyState.loaded);
  }

  void changeState(MyState state) {
    myState = state;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> saveArticleStatus(String articleId, bool isSaved) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setBool(articleId, isSaved);
  }

  Future<void> removeArticleFromReadingList(String articleId) async {
    try {
      myState = MyState.loading;
      _loginData = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final token = _loginData.getString('token') ?? '';
      await _readingListService.deleteReadingList(token: token, id: articleId);
      savedArticleIds.remove(articleId);
      saveArticleStatus(articleId, false);
      myState = MyState.loaded;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      _message = e.toString();
      myState = MyState.failed;
    }
  }

  void toggleArticleSaved(String articleId) {
    if (savedArticleIds.contains(articleId)) {
      savedArticleIds.remove(articleId);
      saveArticleStatus(articleId,
          false); // Menyimpan status false ke dalam SharedPreferences
    } else {
      savedArticleIds.add(articleId);
      saveArticleStatus(
          articleId, true); // Menyimpan status true ke dalam SharedPreferences
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bool isArticleSaved(String articleId) {
    return savedArticleIds.contains(articleId);
  }
}
```

and this is my screen

```
class ArticleListPostWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Articles> articles;

  const ArticleListPostWidget({Key? key, required this.articles})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider =
        Provider.of<ArticleListPostProvider>(context, listen: false);

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: articles.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final article = articles[index];
        return InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, ArticleDetailsScreen.routename,
                arguments: article.id);
          },
          child: Card(
            surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 2,
            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(3),
              ),
            ),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Image.network(
                    article.image ?? '',
                    width: 135,
                    height: 128,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          article.title ?? '',
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 16,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          article.author ?? '',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            color: MyColor.neutralMedium,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 16,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          article.formattedDate,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 10,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            color: MyColor.neutralMedium,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    if (provider.isLoggedIn() == true) {
                      if (provider.isArticleSaved(article.id ?? '')) {
                        provider.toggleArticleSaved(article.id ?? '');
                        await provider
                            .removeArticleFromReadingList(article.id ?? '');
                      } else {
                        provider.toggleArticleSaved(article.id ?? '');
                        showModalBottomSheet(
                          useRootNavigator: true,
                          isScrollControlled: true,
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return Wrap(
                              children: [
                                CustomBottomSheetBuilder(
                                  tinggi:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
                                  isi: [
                                    SaveContent(
                                      articleId: articles[index].id ?? '',
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                  header: true,
                                  judul: 'Save to...',
                                ),
                              ],
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      }
                    } else {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login_screen');
                    }
                  },
                  icon: Consumer<ArticleListPostProvider>(
                    builder: (context, provider, _) {
                      final isArticleSaved =
                          provider.isArticleSaved(article.id ?? '');
                      return isArticleSaved
                          ? Icon(Icons.bookmark, color: MyColor.primaryMain)
                          : const Icon(Icons.bookmark_border);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I want to delete the article data from reading list by using `articleId` but that's not working.